# Подскажите, почему вылетает приложение при эмуляции. Android Studio

Tags: java, android

У меня две активности: empty и Navigation Drawer Activity. На первой есть 4 кнопки (обычные button), одна из которых ведет на вторую активноть (new Intent и т. д.). Всё стандартное, исключая текст на кнопках (первая активность) и задний фон все на той же первой активности, при попытке запустить приложение на эмуляторе и реальном устройстве останавливает приложение.

Может, кто-нибудь знает, почему?

Comment: Прикрепите логи. И код на котором возникает исключение

Comment: А объявлены ли активности в манифесте?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы узнать причину, по которой приложение "**unfortunately stopped**", нужно посмотреть в логи. Увидеть их можно тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажимаете на "**Android Monitor**", выбираете свое устройство и процесс (при запуске приложения это зачастую делается автоматически) 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и наблюдаете свой лог, в котором подробно будет описана "вся жизнь" вашего приложения. Можно также управлять отображаемой информацией и самому логгировать информацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы просили подсказать, почему ваше приложение вылетает - без логов и подробностей никто вам не сможет помочь. Увидев в логе ошибку, вы либо сами сможете исправить ее, либо дополнить свой вопрос, чтобы вам уже помогли эту ошибку исправить.

Comment: Нашла проблему, после обновления теперь нужно тыкать на кнопку со звездочками чтобы все нормально отразилось