# «Приложение XXX остановлено» при отладке

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка, отладчик

Рабочее приложение запускаю дебаггером на девайсе. Появляется белый экран на устройстве. В Android Studio в консоли пишет:

> Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'.

Всё нормально. Нажимаю <kbd>Step Over (F8)</kbd>, ровно как и любую другую, и приложение вылетает.

Выташил из LogCat:

> 06-03 11:33:00.476 16432-16432/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()

06-03 11:33:00.476 16432-16432/? E/Zygote: v2

06-03 11:33:00.476 16432-16432/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10150

06-03 11:33:00.476 16432-16432/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona

06-03 11:33:00.476 16432-16432/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SM-J120F_5.1.1 ver=51

06-03 11:33:00.481 16432-16432/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [1] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J120F_5.1.1_0051

06-03 11:33:00.481 16432-16432/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0

06-03 11:33:00.486 16432-16432/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL

06-03 11:33:00.486 16432-16432/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

06-03 11:33:00.506 16432-16432/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable

06-03 11:33:00.506 16432-16432/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider

06-03 11:33:00.541 16432-16432/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.sapeg.myapplication is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...

06-03 11:33:00.546 16432-16432/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk

06-03 11:33:00.806 16432-16439/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/art: Debugger is active

06-03 11:33:00.946 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: Debugger has connected

06-03 11:33:00.946 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:01.146 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:01.346 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:01.546 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:01.746 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:01.946 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:02.146 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:02.346 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:02.551 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:02.751 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:02.951 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:03.151 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:03.346 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:03.551 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:03.751 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...

06-03 11:33:03.951 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication I/System.out: debugger has settled (1351)

06-03 11:33:29.596 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication A/art: sart/runtime/stack.cc:568] Expected: android.system.StructStat libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.stat(java.lang.String) Found: java.util.ArrayList dalvik.system.DexPathList.splitPaths(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)

06-03 11:33:29.621 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication A/art: sart/runtime/stack.cc:568] Expected: android.system.StructStat libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.stat(java.lang.String) Found: java.util.ArrayList dalvik.system.DexPathList.splitPaths(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean)

06-03 11:33:29.621 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:292] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!

06-03 11:33:29.621 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication A/art: sart/runtime/runtime.cc:292]

06-03 11:33:29.621 16432-16432/com.example.sapeg.myapplication A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 16432 (g.myapplication)

Comment: что делать, когда [получаешь "приложение остановлено"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663645/177345). Полученный стектрейс добавляете в свой вопрос.

Comment: Stack trace добавил