# Подключиться к SOAP из Android

Tags: android, soap

1С Предприетие выдает мне вот такй веб-сервис
http://localhost/veres/ws/wms_tcd?wsdl. Ответ в виде xml. Я хочу получить этот xml результат с этого сервиса.

Пишу

```
package com.example.jaroslavh.ws1;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;

import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpResponseException;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "tns:swtrade-wms#wms_tcd:echo";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "echo";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost/veres/ws/wms_tcd";
    private static final String URL = "http://localhost/veres/ws/wms_tcd?wsdl";
    private TextView tv;
    private String response;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);

        myAsyncTask myRequest = new myAsyncTask();
        myRequest.execute();

    }

    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            tv.setText(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("iTopN", "5");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            httpTransport.debug = true;
            try {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } //send request
            SoapObject result = null;
            try {
                result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("App", "" + result.getProperty(1).toString());
            response = result.getProperty(1).toString();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.jaroslavh.ws1">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

В результате получаю вылет приложения: Unfortunately, WS1 has stopped.

Comment: Скриншот в вашем вопросе лишний. Лучше приложите стектрейс с ошибкой после вылета приложения из AndroidMonitor.

Comment: кого? и как это сделать?

Comment: вот тут падает программа httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Comment: @ЯрославВолодимирович Вы понимаете что ваш эндпоинт стучится к localhost? Это значит что вы общаетесь с своей же машиной.

Comment: понимаю, у меня и сервис и андроид студио на одной машине, а в чем проблема?

Comment: Ну и какая [ошибка при падении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/663645/14141) на этой строке?

Comment: вот лог ошибки http://paste1c.ru/GBP